# How can I delete duplicates records in a table efficiently

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

I know there are several options to delete duplicate rows,  eg:

- ROWID
- Analytical fn's like Rank(), row_number()

What would be the most efficient way?

Answer (score 5):

If you can afford to have a temporary table, then creating new table with the distinct values of the old one is a lot faster that deleting the rows. Something like:

```
create table no_dupes
as 
select min(id) as id,
       col_a,
       col_b,
       col_c,
       min(col_d) as col_d,
       min(col_e) as col_e
from table_with_dupes
group by col_a, col_b, col_c;
```

Of course this has the drawback of needing to re-recreate all indexes and constraints. But in my experience it way faster - especially if you are deleting a large number of rows in a large table.

Answer (score 4):

As you said, there are many options. My personal favorite is

```
delete from dups
  where rowid in (
                  select rid
                    from (
                          select row_number() over (partition by a,b,c order by a,b,c ) rn
                                ,rowid rid
                            from dups
                          )
                   where rn > 1
                  )
;
```

Being `dups` the table with the duplicates and `a,b,c` the columns to check.

Does one FTS (or index scan, if `a,b,c` is in the index) followed by access by rowid to delete.

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/68a87/17) to check/play.

Comment: I wonder if this one is faster: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/68a87/18